# KDEInit could not launch '/usr/bin/apper' after closing Apper

Tags: debian, package-management, kde

Plasma gives me the following error after closing Apper:

> KDEInit could not launch '/usr/bin/apper'

Prior to this I had [a problem of high CPU load](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382382/high-cpu-load-kded5-plasmashell-dbus-daemon) and rebuild the kservice desktop file with kbuildsycoca5, restarted plasma and then restarted my PC. I also cleaned cache and memory with BleachBit. And I tried to uninstall OpenJDK and deleted the "suspicious" files `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo` and `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-gcj-6.jinfo`. However I already tried reinstalling OpenJDK which also restored those 2 files. Note that when running `sudo dpkg --verify` those 2 files are now shown too. Edit: `debsums|grep -v OK` tells me they are missing.

Also note that otherwise apper seems to be working fine.

When running `sudo apper` I get this in the console:

> QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
> QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-mime-type"
> QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-package-name"
> QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-provide-file"
> QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "install-catalog"
> QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "remove-package-by-file"
> Reusing existing ksycoca
> Recreating ksycoca file ("/root/.cache/ksycoca5_...", version 303)
> Still in the time dict (i.e. deleted files) ("apps")
> Menu "applications-kmenuedit.menu" not found.
> new: "/usr/share/applications/openjdk-8-policytool.desktop"
> Saving
> QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
> QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
> Invalid pixmap specified.
> Invalid pixmap specified.
> QObject::connect: No such slot MainUi::setCaption(QString)
> QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'ApperKCM')

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE. Still new to GNU/Linux and any help is welcome.

<sup>Edit: It works again after I reinstalled those 2 packages via `apt-get install --reinstall gcj-6-jre-headles` & `apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64`. However I still frequently get this message when closing apper.</sup>

Edit: one should not run apper as root (with sudo)!

Answer (score 0):

try in terminal:
"sudo apper" 
that should fix that problem.

Just set to run from user account.

Right Click on Apper icon: Properties>Program>Advanced options>Run as another user: "your user name"

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to right click on the icon in the launcher not on the desktop after starting sudo apper. Then click edit app from there and get to the advanced options as described above.